I need help troubleshooting buzzing noise in microphone
Recently, I purchased a cheap lavalier microphone, the Boya BY-M1, and noticed that the recordings have a constant electric buzzing noise, similar to the sound produced by a Tesla coil. This issue only occurs when my laptop is plugged in, leading me to believe it’s a case of electrical interference. I tested the microphone on another laptop from a different brand, and it too produced the same electrical noise whenever it was plugged in. I also tried different wall outlets in various rooms and even used a power strip, but nothing seems to fix the issue.
Is it safe to assume that the wiring in my house might be faulty? Can someone advise me on what to do? For context, I live in an Asian country.

I'd suggest "cheap lavalier microphone" is probably the main reason

Do you have other microphones? Any problems recording with those? Am I correct understanding that if you run the laptop on battery power you don't have problems? Are you using an interface? What interface?

I am not using any interface, and yes, if I run the laptop on battery power, then I don't have any problems. Here's a recording of the noise I was talking about: https://sndup.net/5cvf7/

The laptop is the problem. Normal line noise on the power supply is bleeding into the microphone input. This is why you don’t get the noise when you’re on battery. The power adapter and mic input are not properly isolated from each other. If you don’t want to buy anything, your best option is probably to only record on battery power.
